# Center button under form in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap, center

i have some problems with Bootstrap. i centered form and button by using `span6 offset3` and don't know how to center button under this form right now. i tried with `text-align: center` but still it's more on the left.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <form>
                <input class="input-xxlarge" type="text" placeholder="Email..">
                <p style="line-height: 70px; text-align: center;"><button type="submit" class="btn">Confirm</button></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 0 auto` on the button element? I am suspecting that text-align didn't work is because the button is declared as a block-level element.

Comment: @Terry i've tried margin, button is on the same place:/

Comment: You need to replicate the problem in a Fiddle for us to help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove that `<p>` tag and add the button inside a `<div class="form-actions">` like this:

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Confirm</button>
</div>
```

an then augment the CSS class with:

```
.form-actions {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's a JS Bin demo: http://jsbin.com/ijozof/2

---

Look for `form-actions` at the `Bootstrap` doc here:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Comment: hey, looks good in JSBin but take a look on pic up. still the same place.

Comment: Note: that CSS code on my answer must come after the Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: thin line show up and i think button is in center now. maybe there is a problem with form?

Comment: Can you create a JS Bin with all the HTML markup you have? In the picture you show on your question I can't see a thin line. Maybe your current CSS code is interfering...

Comment: http://i45.tinypic.com/2rz83mc.png .form-actions has also margin,padding-top, border etc. so i paste only that's what you gave. same on html. but as you can see on picture(that's whole screen), button's on the left.

Comment: In your JSBin you're forgetting to close one `<div>` tag. It looks OK here: http://jsbin.com/otusoq/2

Comment: hey,it works! button's on the center, at least i've changed form width to smaller;)

Comment: Nice to know you got it working! :D These kind of things are difficult to spot since we don't have the full code to debug here.

Answer (score 15):

With Bootstrap 3, you can use the 'text-center' styling attribute.

```
<div class="col-md-3 text-center"> 
  <button id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Press Me!</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **Bootstrap 4**, try this:

```
<div class="mx-auto text-center">
    <button id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Press Me!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Width:100%` and `text-align:center` would work in my experience

```
<p style="display:block; line-height: 70px; width:100%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;"><button type="submit" class="btn">Confirm</button></p>
```

Comment: button's bigger and stick to left again

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this class

```
class="pager"

<p class="pager" style="line-height: 70px;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Confirm</button>
</p>
```

I tried mine within a `<div class=pager><button etc etc></div>`  which worked well

See http://getbootstrap.com/components/ look under Pagination -> Pager

This looks like the correct bootstrap class to center this, `text-align: center;` is meant for text not images and blocks etc.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this `<center></center>`

```
<div class="form-actions">
            <center>
                    <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary ">
                        Sign In <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
                    </button>
            </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block w-50 mx-auto">Search</button>
```

Look something like this
[image]

Complete Form code -

```
<form id="submit">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mt-5" id="search-city" 
           placeholder="Search City">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 btn-sm btn-block w-50 
            mx-auto">Search</button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap, the correct way is to use the offset class.  Use math to determine the left offset.  Example:   You want a button full width on mobile, but 1/3 width and centered on tablet, desktop, large desktop.

So out of 12 "bootstrap" columns, you're using 4 to offset, 4 for the button, then 4 is blank to the right.

See if that works!

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap you can simply use class `text-center`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form>
            <input class="input-xxlarge" type="text" placeholder="Email..">
        </form>

        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/legionar/mxouvr6n/)

Answer (score -1):

Try giving

default width, display it with block and center it with margin: 0 auto;

like this:

```
<p style="display:block; line-height: 70px; width:200px; margin:0 auto;"><button type="submit" class="btn">Confirm</button></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's working completely try this:

```
<div class="button pull-left" style="padding-left:40%;" >
```